# cascade delete doesn't work

Tags: java, hibernate, annotations, cascade

I have problem with Hibernate. My domains are Voucher, Offer, ExtraUser, Term and TermUserRegistration. They look like:

```
@Entity(name = "Voucher")
@Table(name = "extra_vouchers")
public class Voucher implements Cloneable, Serializable{
```

with ID and other attributes... Voucher is some coupon. Every OfferDB (it is offer.. for example some trip by boat or something..) has more than one vouchers. Every Extrauser can own also more than one vouchers.

There are also some reservations to the Term of Offer (concrete dates) - TermUserRegistration - and every one registration means one Voucher.

then Offer:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "extra_offers")
public class OfferDB implements Cloneable, Serializable {

@OneToMany (mappedBy="offer")
private List<Voucher> vouchers = new ArrayList<Voucher>();
```

Id and other properties included...

then ExtraUser:

```
@Entity(name = "extrauser")
@Table(name = "extra_users")
public class ExtraUser implements Cloneable, Serializable {

@OneToMany (fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="owner")
private List<Voucher> vouchers = new ArrayList<Voucher>();
```

then Term:

```
@Entity(name = "Term")
@Table(name = "extra_term")
public class Term implements Cloneable, Serializable{

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "extra_term_user", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "term_id") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "term_user_id") })  
private List<TermUserRegistration> users = new ArrayList<TermUserRegistration>();
```

and TermUserRegistration:

```
@Entity(name = "TermUserRegistration")
@Table(name = "extra_term_users")
public class TermUserRegistration implements Cloneable, Serializable{

@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Voucher extraVoucher;
```

Now I want to ask you if there is some way to delete TermUserRegistration by ID and delete also its connected relations like Voucher... I have a problem with some cascade delete exceptions.

**My method looks**

```
@Override
public void unregisterUserFromTerm(Term termToExport, TermUserRegistration termUser) {
    Voucher voucherToDisable = voucherDao.findById(termUser.getExtraVoucher().getId());
    FreeVoucher freeVoucherToEdit = freeVoucherDao.findVoucherByCodeAndOfferId(termUser.getExtraVoucher().getCode(), termToExport.getOffer().getId());  

    Long l = Long.parseLong(String.valueOf(termToExport.getOffer().getId()));
    Offer offer = offerDao.findById(l);     

    ExtraUser extraUser = userDao.findById(termUser.getExtraUser().getId());

    termToExport.getUsers().remove(termUser);
    extraTermDao.update(termToExport);
    extraTermUserDao.delete(termUser);

    offer.getVouchers().remove(voucherToDisable);   
    offerDao.update(offer);

    extraUser.getVouchers().remove(voucherToDisable);
    userDao.update(extraUser);

    voucherDao.update(voucherToDisable);
    voucherDao.delete(voucherToDisable);

    freeVoucherToEdit.setFree(true);
    freeVoucherDao.update(freeVoucherToEdit);
}
```

but I am getting

SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [edit] in context with path [/project] threw exception [Execution failed :deleted instance passed to update(): [null entity name#null]] with root cause
org.hibernate.ObjectDeletedException: deleted instance passed to update(): [null entity name#null]

Comment: Are you asking if there is a way to delete the one connected voucher when a TermUserRegistration is deleted?  The Voucher does not connect to anything else and the TermUserRegistration does not connect to anything else so I'm not sure how you'd get to ExtraUser objects, Term objects, or Offer objects.

Comment: What are these cascade delete exceptions?

Comment: ExtraUser is connected to TermUser (aka termUserRegistration)  @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
 private ExtraUser extraUser; ..there are information about phone number, address etc. Term is maybe redundant in this problem... but Vouchers are included in Offer also, right?

Comment: Try setting orphanRemoval in mapping. `@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sorry for asking such a stupid question. I did not know too much about (cascade = CascadeType.ALL). There was a problem.